# Low level programming: How to find data in a memory of another running process?

Tags: memory, assembly, process, reverse-engineering, low-level

I am trying to write a statistics tool for a game by extracting values from game's process memory (as there is no other way). The biggest challenge is to find out required addresses that store data I am interested. What makes it even more harder is dynamic memory allocation - I need to find not only addresses that store data but also pointers to those memory blocks, because addresses are changing every time game restarts.

For now I am just manually searching game memory using memory editor (ArtMoney), and looking for addresses that change their values as data changes (or don't change). After address is found I am looking for a pointer that points to this memory block in a similar way.

I wonder what techniques/tools exist for such tasks? Maybe there are some articles I can read? Is mastering disassembler the only way to go? For example game trainers are solving similar tasks, but they make them in days and I am struggling already for weeks.

Thanks.

PS. It's all under windows.

Comment: Can you specify which platform?

Answer (score 1):

> Is mastering disassembler the only way to go?

Yes; go download WinDbg from http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx, or if you've got some money to blow, IDA Pro is probably the best tool for doing this

Comment: But even with disassembler, what is the strategy for finding values? Disassembling hundreds of megabytes and trying to figure out what is going on there looks like impossible task to me. Where to start?

Comment: Don't just search through all of memory, try to find the function that updates the value you're interested in; set debugger breakpoints that print stuff every time you hit them

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to code in C, it is easy to search for memory values. If you don't know C, this [page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/minememoryreader.aspx) might point you to your solution if you can code in C#. It will not be hard to port the C# they have to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [DynInst](http://www.dyninst.org/) (Dynamic Instrumentation).  In particular, look at the [Dynamic Probe Class Library (DPCL)](http://www.dyninst.org/tools.html).  These tools will let you attach to running processes via the debugger interface and insert your own instrumentation (via special probe classes) into them while they're running.  You could probably use this to instrument the routines that access your data structures and trace when the values you're interested in are created or modified.

You might have an easier time doing it this way than doing everything manually.  There are a bunch of papers on those pages you can look at to see how other people built similar tools, too.

I believe the Windows support is maintained, but I have not used it myself.